# how to open and excel file in excel from .netcore console application

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I'm looking for my program just to open an excel file that I already have created.

**Question**

How can you make a .netcore console app just open a file? in this case an excel file in excel?

Comment: `Process.Start("explorer", "myexcelfile.xlsx")` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the Answer. Here I'm attempting to download libraries and move things around

Comment: It should also be working with only the path parameter. `Start("myfile")`

Comment: @Kalten if you post your answer i would accept and delete my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start("explorer", "myexcelfile.xlsx")

Comment: @Kalten  if you repost this i will gladly give you credit for this answer.

Comment: It's ok as is. Thx

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus has an unofficial port... it seems to works alright. Alternatively you could extract the excel as a zip and then use a xml editor.

Comment: The official version is available too